# Spring Security: Not able to configure method security with java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I am struggling to configure method security with java configured spring security. My configuration works without any problem, until I use the @Secured annotation within any controller.

Spring Security Config: (java config)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**","/css/**", "/less/**","/img/**","/js/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ShaPasswordEncoder shaPasswordEncoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);
        auth
          .jdbcAuthentication()
              .dataSource(dataSource)
              .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
              .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery())
              .passwordEncoder(shaPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority("BASIC_PERMISSION")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/success-login", true)
            .failureUrl("/error-login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/process-login")
            .usernameParameter("security_username")
            .passwordParameter("security_password")
            .permitAll() 
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .key("04E87501B3F04DB297ADB74FA8BD48CA")
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
    }

    private String getUserQuery() {
        return "SELECT username as username, password as password, active as enabled "
                + "FROM employee "
                + "WHERE username = ?";
    }

    private String getAuthoritiesQuery() {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT employee.username as username, permission.name as authority "
                + "FROM employee, employee_role, role, role_permission, permission "
                + "WHERE employee.id = employee_role.employee_id "
                + "AND role.id = employee_role.role_id "
                + "AND role.id = role_permission.role_id "
                + "AND permission.id = role_permission.permission_id "
                + "AND employee.username = ? "
                + "AND employee.active = 1";
    }

}
```

As soon as I add the `@Secured("EMPLOYEE_DELETE")` Annotation to any controller method,I receive following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
```

So I added an `AuthenticationManager` bean:

```
@Bean 
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

But this has another error as result:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer@34e81675 to already built object
```

It seems that I have to share the `authenticationManagerBean` with the configured `jdbcAuthentication` but I am not able to do this. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't suppose you could provide a complete example that reproduces this issue? I have had trouble reproducing it in an isolated test. If you are able, please update this or provide a complete sample on the JIRA https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2477 Another thing that would help is providing a complete stacktrace of the "IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean .." and tell me if you are trying to Autowire the AuthenticationManager anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind...I was finally able to reproduce this consistently. Of course it happens right after I post on here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds as though you are encountering an ordering issue as described in [SEC-2477](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2477).

As a workaround, you can should be able to use the configure method with the authenticationManagerBean method. Do not use the @Autowired AuthenticationManagerBuilder approach.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ShaPasswordEncoder shaPasswordEncoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);
    auth
      .jdbcAuthentication()
          .dataSource(dataSource)
          .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery())
          .passwordEncoder(shaPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean 
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Comment: I've been trolling through Google to figure out how to wire up Spring MVC to work with Spring Security. In contrast to your comment here, the only configuration I've found that works is the one from the following pull request of yours: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/pull/2. Can you explain when one approach should be used over another?